# get unique values as well as the empty string in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

How can i modify this code to also give the empty strings in the range

```
Sub GetUniqueAndCount()

    Dim d As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In Selection
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(tmp) > 0 Then d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
    Next c

    For Each k In d.keys
        Debug.Print k, d(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the test for the length of tmp and it should do it:

```
Sub GetUniqueAndCount()

    Dim d As Object, c As Range, k, tmp As String

    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In Selection
        tmp = Trim(c.Value)
        d(tmp) = d(tmp) + 1
    Next c

    For Each k In d.keys
        Debug.Print k, d(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't believe you can set a dictionary key to a zero-length string or vbNullString.

Comment: I was not sure too, but I tried d("") = 1 and it worked.